# Квадратная матрица и сумма отрицательных элементов строк

Tags: c++, матрицы

Для квадратной матрицы с `M * M` чисел определить сумму элементов, расположенных ниже главной диагонали, среди строк, начинающихся с отрицательного элемента.

Вот код, но он не правильно находит сумму. Что не так?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    int i = 0, j = 0, M, sum = 1;
    cout << "Введите кол-во строк в матрице: ";
    cin >> M;
    int** A = new int* [M];
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        A[i] = new int[j];
    srand(time(NULL));
    cout << "Матрица: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = (5 - rand() % 10);
            cout << setw(3) << A[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < M; j++)
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            if ((A[i][j] < 0) && (i > j)) {
                sum = sum + A[i][j];
            }

    cout << "Сумма элементов строки= " << sum << endl;
    delete[]A;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У Вас в коде несколько проблем:

1. Переменные `i` и `j` не нужны. Вы в циклах обьявляете свои локальные переменные.
2. Почему `sum` инициализируется еденицей? Должна ведь быть нулём.
3. Строка `A[i] = new int[j];` должна иметь вид `A[i] = new int[M];`. Матрица ведь должна быть квадратная. Ещё й `j` в данной точке программы равно нулю.
4. В цикле суммирования Вы обходите всю матрицу, хотя этого можно и не делать. Да и с проверками беда. Вот возможная реализация:

```
for (int i = 1; i < M; i++)           // Начинаем сразу со второй строки матрицы
{
    if (A[i][0] >= 0)                 // Будем считать, только если первый элемент строки >= 0
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)   // Идет по строке до элемента диагонали
        {
            sum += A[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

5. Удалять двумерный динамический массив нужно в обратном порядке его создания:

```
// Удаляем каждую строку матрицы
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
{
    delete[] A[i];
}

// Удаляем массив, который хранил указатели на строки матрицы
delete[] A;
```